# A problem occurred configuring project':react-native-audio-recorder-player' >compileSdkVersion is not specified,while running react-native run-android

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Whenever I try running react-native run-android, I am getting the following error:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-audio-recorder-player'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified.
```

build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = 28
    
    androidXAnnotation = "1.1.0"
    androidXBrowser = "1.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation. If none specified and
 *   // "index.android.js" exists, it will be used. Otherwise "index.js" is
 *   // default. Can be overridden with ENTRY_FILE environment variable.
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // https://reactnative.dev/docs/performance#enable-the-ram-format
 *   bundleCommand: "ram-bundle",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

/**
 * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
 *
 * This should be set on project.ext.react and mirrored here.  If it is not set
 * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
 * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
 */
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sheolife"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
          release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
               signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation project(':react-native-android-open-settings')
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation project(':react-native-audio')
    implementation 'com.clevertap.android:clevertap-android-sdk:4.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.4'
    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"
    implementation project(':react-native-audio-recorder-player')
     compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.+'
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
      exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "sheolife",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./src/assets/fonts/"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start-web": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test-web": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject-web": "react-scripts eject",
    "prettier": "prettier --write './src'",
    "yarn-ios": "yarn ios --simulator `iPhone 6s` --verbose",
    "clear-modules": "rm -rf node_modules; rm -f package-lock.json; rm -f yarn.lock"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/art": "^1.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.0",
    "@react-native-community/cameraroll": "^4.0.2",
    "@react-native-community/cli": "^4.14.0",
    "@react-native-community/clipboard": "^1.2.3",
    "@react-native-community/hooks": "^2.6.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^6.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/voice": "^1.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.9.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.11.4",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.3.10",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.4.0",
    "@twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input": "^1.3.11",
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "clevertap": "^1.1.1",
    "clevertap-react-native": "^0.5.0",
    "i18n-js": "^3.8.0",
    "loadash": "^1.0.0",
    "lodash.memoize": "^4.1.2",
    "materialize-css": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
    "modal-react-native-web": "^0.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "qs": "^6.9.4",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-art": "^16.5.1",
    "react-datepicker": "^3.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.1",
    "react-dropdown": "^1.9.0",
    "react-materialize": "^3.9.3",
    "react-native": "0.63.2",
    "react-native-android-open-settings": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-animated-ellipsis": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-animated-loader": "^0.0.9",
    "react-native-audio": "^4.3.0",
    "react-native-audio-recorder-player": "^2.6.1",
    "react-native-auto-height-image": "^3.2.4",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1129.0",
    "react-native-countdown-component": "^2.7.1",
    "react-native-create-thumbnail": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-custom-datetimepicker": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^3.2.8",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-debugger": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-dialog": "^6.1.2",
    "react-native-drawer": "^2.5.1",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^3.7.1",
    "react-native-eject": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-htmlview": "^0.16.0",
    "react-native-image-base64": "^0.1.4",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.33.2",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^3.1.4",
    "react-native-indicators": "^0.17.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-localize": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.6.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.5.0",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.3",
    "react-native-picker-view": "^1.0.9",
    "react-native-pie": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-pie-chart": "^1.0.13",
    "react-native-progress-bar-animated": "^1.0.6",
    "react-native-progress-circle": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-pull-to-refresh": "^2.1.3",
    "react-native-range-slider": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-raw-bottom-sheet": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-read-more-text": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.8",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.11.0",
    "react-native-searchable-dropdown": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-share": "^5.1.4",
    "react-native-side-drawer": "^1.2.8",
    "react-native-side-menu": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-simple-toast": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-sound": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-speedometer-chart": "^0.7.5",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.0.6",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.15.2",
    "react-native-textinput-effects": "^0.6.1",
    "react-native-thumbnail-video": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-tts": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.1.0",
    "react-native-video": "^5.1.1",
    "react-native-video-player": "^0.10.1",
    "react-native-view-shot": "^3.1.2",
    "react-native-web": "^0.14.2",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.3.2",
    "react-otp-input": "^2.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-render-html": "^0.6.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-modal": "^2.0.0-rc3",
    "react-router-native": "^5.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "victory-native": "^35.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.11.2",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^5.0.2",
    "jest": "^26.4.2",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.7",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.63.0",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.5",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.3.1",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.7.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "homepage": "."
}
```

Things I tried ->

1. removed android and ios folders
2. react-native eject
3. ./gradlew clean

and

1. removed node_modules
2. npm install
3. react-native run-android

However nothing is working, kindly help me out here, been stuck since two days, any leads would be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue when I ejected my expo app, If you check out the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-audio-recorder-player) of react-native-audio-recorder-player they have mentioned that for version 3.0.0+ codebase has been re-written to kotlin for Android and swift for iOS,

So you need to add plugin for kotlin inside your build.gradle file,

after adding, your dependencies will look something like

hope this resolves your issue

```
   dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3',
    classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3"),
    classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.0")  //kotlin plugin

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your **android gradle** file

> file path -> ProjectName/android/build.gradle

**Add below code**

```
buildscript {
  ext {
      minSdkVersion = 24
      kotlinVersion = '1.5.0'
      }

  repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()
  }

  dependencies {
     classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in you android **build.gradle** file

> Your Project - android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
       ext {
             buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
             minSdkVersion = 24
             compileSdkVersion = 31
             targetSdkVersion = 31
             kotlinVersion = '1.5.0'
..............

dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
........
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Check your java version, I resolved it by uprgading the java version on mac using brew to zulu 17.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).